# Using Selenium on https web application that runs over vpn

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, popup, vpn

First of all, I need to state that I am total beginner with Selenium.
I am trying to test an application in firefox browser using Selenium. Due to security issues the application works only over vpn.

My problem occurs with the following steps; I create the webdriver and navigate to the start (login) page of application. I get an "Authorization request" popup. If I cancel the popup, then I get to a page that states "Connection is not secure" (it's https address). After I get passed that, I lose the part where Selenium program should populate username and password and it just stays on the login page.

My question, is there a way to start Selenium testing on an application so that it is already opened and prepared (ie logged in) in browser? I am not happy that username and password are hard-coded in Selenium code.

If that is not possible, how do I skip that authorization popup and problem with non-secure connection? How do I populate username and password in safest way?
Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium-java-3.0.1\\geckodriver.exe");
    // I tried also with this code bellow in comment, but it did not work, it did not even get to login page
    //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);      
    //Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
    //alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword("cfadmin", "20lipim18"));
    driver.get("https://Application_login_page.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("[@id='login']")).sendKeys("Username");
```

}

Comment: Can you consider to showcase your work please? Thanks

Comment: I did research. Also, I already tried suggested first solution earlier (found it here) and few other solutions but nothing works. I was hoping for some advice not criticism. I will add my code here but that will tell you nothing.

Comment: @BiljanaM. A couple of points: 1.As you mentioned `I get "Authorisation request" popup` can you share a snapshot of the "Authorisation request" popup please? 2. `"Connection is not secure"` we would be able to handle it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> if it's possible, is there a way to start Selenium testing on application that is already opened and prepared (logged) in browser?

Try using firefox profile. Since selenium open fresh instance of browser by default. You can use your own firefox frofile.

This is a code to implement a profile, which can be embedded in the selenium code.

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
// this will create an object for the Firefox profile
FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
// this will Initialize the Firefox driver
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile)
```

It will also maintain the session means you are already login to the application in firefox(default profile). Then if you execute the script, you will see that you are already logged in to the application.

Comment: This solution works great (or at least concept, I have done this with Chrome but not FF) -- especially if you need persistent local storage data to be present in something like IndexedDB for client usage in the selenium tests, but don't want to keep re-initializing/fetching that data for each test.

Comment: This does work. So far, no "Authentication" popup, and it looks fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to open already authorised page, you have to have to pass username and password through selenium script.

You may use below code to do the authentication

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);      
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(username, password));
```

Comment: or can pass the username and password in url itself

Comment: I already tried this, it was an answer in similar question with similar problem, but it did not work.